# Удалить все файлы указанные в списке и написать о том что они удалены в отдельный файл

Tags: linux, bash

Есть задача: Удалить все файлы из заданного списка, если файл существовал, написать Имя_файла удалено ( в отдельный файл), если же файл не удалился или его не существовало написать об этом, тоже в отдельный файл. Попробовал написать вот это :

```
#!/bin/bash
del=0 
noexist=0 
echo " enter file name " 
read filename 
cat $filename | while read I 
do 
if [ -f ${I} ]; then
rm -f ${I} 
echo  " $I ( deleted ) " >>deleted.txt 
((del++)) 
else 
echo  " $I  ( no exist or cant be deleted ) " >>noexist.txt 
((noexist++))
fi 
done 
echo  " $del ( deleted ) " >>deleted.txt 
echo  " $noexist ( no exist or cant be deleted ) " >>noexist.txt
```

Но ничего дельного не получилось, не мог ли бы вы подсказать, в чем я ошибся?

Comment: Понял что все работает нормально) 
Были лишние пробелы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нечто вроде:

```
#!/bin/bash

del=0 
noexist=0 

# Цикл удаления файлов
while [[ 0 ]]
do
    echo " enter file name "
    read filename
    
    if [ "$filename" = q ]
    then
        echo "Завершаем работу: $filename"
        break
    fi
    
    if [ ! -f $filename ]
    then
        echo "Файл $filename не существует"
        let noexist=noexist+1
    else
        echo "Удаляем файл $filename"
        rm -f $filename
        let del=del+1
    fi
done

echo  " $del ( deleted ) " >>deleted.txt 
echo  " $noexist ( no exist or cant be deleted ) " >>noexist.txt
```